# Job Position Changed Before Hire

Tags: new-job, job-change

My new job position just changed because another team is missing more members. I haven't even started the job yet. I'm not quite happy with the change. I'm not sure I would have accepted the job if I knew it would be for this new position. But the pay is still the same. Is there anything I can do about this? Should I try to argue against the job change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there anything I can do about this?

Yes.

> Should I try to ***argue*** against the job change?

No. Do not argue. Even if you dislike the company or the people there, leave a good impression, because some day later those people may come back to you as a member of your team / to deal a business with you.

Instead, I would ask the company more information about this new job change. Treat it as an entirely new job advertisement. What would be my responsibility? What is my expected skill set? Is the working hours and benefits (e.g. annual leaves) still the same as the previous one? Who would be my supervisor? What is the type of business that this team engages?

### Action plan

If you have already found out the details of the new position (sounds like you have), you can now decide your next action:

- If you like it, go along with it
- If you think the previously discussed salary does not justify this new position, you can politely request a salary negotiation
- If you don't like it, just reply you don't think this new job position is a good match to you, and thank the company for their interest

Note item #3: have you signed a contract? If no, you have no obligations. If yes, job position and title are usually stated in the contract. If the company now asks you to work in another position, they have to give you another contract. Which means, either way, you can exit the situation.

### Do not

Do not just shout to the company or accuse them as being dishonest. Maybe a team desperately needs talent, and the company decided that it is OK to use candidates for another position in another team. Or, maybe some very good candidate suddenly appears, and the company has to relocate someone to another team. Either way, if I am the recruitment manager, I would not be offended if a candidate say "No" in this kind of situation.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I thanked them for them the new position. Asked the reason for the change and asked them if I had the option to choose what position I liked. But looks I didn't have a choice, as that team is short-handed. Pretty disappointed. I most likely will accept the decision and make the best of it. I understand the company's position. Does feel a little bit unfair though.